# Why does beginUpdates/endUpdates reset tableView postion and how to stop it from doing so?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Im using a NSFetchedResultsController in my UITableView and in the

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
and 
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
```

i have a call to beginUpdates/endUpdates per apples docs. The problem is it seems that every time it makes this call it resets the table position to the top. Any ideas why its doing this and if there is a way to avoid the table position reset?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of beginUpdates/endUpdates, can't you just call `[myTableView reloadData];`? Maybe there's something I'm not getting...

Comment: What happens if im inserting 100 rows, i would be calling reloadData 100 times after every insert?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the indexPath of the current row for example

```
NSIndexPath *pastIP=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]
```

and after update

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:pastIP animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Comment: wouldnt this scroll the table to the top as mentioned above and then only scroll it back to the pastIP giving you an up/down effect in the tableView? Not that desirable.

Comment: What im saying is that you will still see the table scroll up to the top after the update and then scroll back to the last indexPath as you suggest above, which would look kinda funny?

Comment: Look at this http://bit.ly/assXmb if it could not solve your poblem, come back to me, will do something..